# Hibernate FetchMode = Join doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, criteria-api

I see Hibernate is firing multiple queries even with FetchMode=JOIN

Below is my Entity classes

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "person")
 public class PersonJPA{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "person_id")
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long personId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personId",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
  private Set<AddressJPA> address;
  ......
 }
```

And

```
 @Table(name = "address")
 public class AddressJPA {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "address_id")
  @GeneratedValue
  private long addressId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
  private PersonJPA personId;

 }
```

How do i write JPA CriteriaQuery which selects PersonJAP with AddressJPA list for the given personId ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to retrieve a PersonJPA object for a given person id, such that its associated AddressJPA set collection is also loaded? In that case, you need a FETCH JOIN.

In Criteria API:

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PersonJPA> query = cb .createQuery(PersonJPA.class);
Root<PersonJPA> person = query.from(PersonJPA.class);
query.fetch("address");
query.select(person);
ParameterExpression<Long> p = cb.parameter(Long.class);
query.where(cb.equal(cb.get("personId"), p));
```

In JP QL:

```
SELECT p FROM PersonJPA p JOIN FETCH p.address
WHERE p.personId = :p
```

Alternatively, you might want to specify the fetch mode (EAGER) in annotations (since by default associated collections are lazily loaded):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "personId",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<AddressJPA> address;
```

@Fetch annotation is Hibernate specific and not from JPA. It specifies strategy on how data should be fetch.
See more info [here](http://www.solidsyntax.be/2013/10/17/fetching-collections-hibernate/).